# How to Calculate Days From Two Dates in Swift [same dates should count as "I" day ]

Tags: ios, swift, date, calendar

Hi I am Calculating days from two dates and I am taking same dates to apply leave and that difference should be "1" leave and my code is calculating as "0"

my code:

```
            fromDateTextField.text = 29-06-2019
            toDateTextField.text = 29-06-2019

            let startDate = fromDateTxtField.text
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
            let formatedStartDate = dateFormatter.date(from: startDate!)
            let currentDate = toDateTxtField.text
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
            let formatedEndDate = dateFormatter.date(from: currentDate!)
            print(formatedEndDate)
            print(formatedStartDate)
            let components1 = Set<Calendar.Component>([.day])
            let differenceOfDate = Calendar.current.dateComponents(components1, from: formatedStartDate!, to: formatedEndDate!)
            print (differenceOfDate.day)
```

output I am getting is "0"

Comment: Why not just add 1 to the result? I assume the difference between 29-06-2019 and 30-06-2019 should be 2?

Comment: fromDateTextField and toDateTextField same date?. If you want calculate more detail you have to add time intervals and time zones e.g yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ

Comment: @joakim sir just got same idea thats working fine thank you